# MySQL Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which is returning an error. Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with my query? I looked at it again and again but everything seems fine to me.

Query

```
SELECT cities.latitude as lat, cities.longitude as long, cities.name as ctn, states.name as stn, countries.name as cn FROM cities
LEFT JOIN states ON cities.state_id = states.id
LEFT JOIN countries ON states.country_id = countries.id
WHERE cities.id = :id
```

Error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'long, ct3.name as ctn FROM cities LEFT JOIN state...' at line 1 in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Long` is a [**MySQL Reserved word**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).

This means you need to encase it in backtick quotes to use it as a name, so the below should resolve your issue:

```
SELECT cities.latitude as lat, cities.longitude as `long`, cities.name as ctn, states.name as stn, countries.name as cn FROM cities
LEFT JOIN states ON cities.state_id = states.id
LEFT JOIN countries ON states.country_id = countries.id
WHERE cities.id = :id
```

Alternatively, rename your column identifier:

```
SELECT cities.latitude as citylat, cities.longitude as citylong, cities.name as ctn, states.name as stn, countries.name as cn FROM cities
LEFT JOIN states ON cities.state_id = states.id
LEFT JOIN countries ON states.country_id = countries.id
WHERE cities.id = :id
```